# Better way to print data to external JavaScript files

Tags: php, javascript, backend, frontend

### Briefing:

A PHP file that prints a HTML markup with a `table` tag full of data and a JS file that renders that data in a Google Chart.

### Though:

I don't thing that's reasonable to make an Ajax call only to get the same data that the PHP file is printing in the `table` tag

### Solutions: (?)

1. Makes the PHP file prints a `script` tag bellow/above the `table` tag with the data JSON encoded to a variable.
2. Prints the data within each corresponding `tr` tag with the HTML5 `data-` attribute then render the Google Chart by that data printed in the `table` tag
3. **What you would do?**

#### Another example:

Printing the application base URL to let the JS files knows about it.

---

## EDIT

I thing that I found a elegant and nice solution for that: **meta tags**.

Meta-tags are just about meta information about the document. So things like:

`<meta name="baseurl" content="<?php echo $baseurl ?>">`

and/or

`<meta name="users" content="<?php echo json_encode($users) ?>">`

Is nice because will avoid putting `<script>` tags in view-partials and obtrusive `data-` attributes in html tags.

Any way, I'm not quite satisfied yet. I'll keep looking for solutions and hearing people.

Comment: UP for presenting question nicely.

Comment: I'd go for the JSON method, printing the data to a variable and then using that to generate the chart.

Comment: #1 - definitely! For one, you will have the least amount of data flowing over the network to achieve the same thing.

Comment: #2 is nice because you don't need to serve any script content in your HTML, though. You can have a general library for turning it into a Google Chart that reads the `data-*` attributes then which doesn't need to be transmitted via AJAX.

Comment: @SudiptaChatterjee How is that less data than #2?

Comment: Both are valid, but the first option is probably better for larger datasets. I voted to close as not constructive, as you're asking for opinions here (see the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask)).

Comment: @bfavaretto You can't do that - you can't answer the question **and** vote to close...that's hypocritical! :)

Comment: @Ian I didn't answer the question, I added a comment.

Comment: @bfavaretto 1. It was a joke, 2. You "answered" the question, 3. It was a joke

Comment: Uh, I guess my joke detector was off! :) @Ian

Comment: @bfavaretto Sorry about that

Comment: @LeoCavalcante No problem, just keep that in mind for your future questions. Unfortunately, this one isn't what the community considers "a good fit for our Q&A format". Hope we can help you more next time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My choice will depend on how often this data changes :

- if changes a lot, would load the page with no data, and make a HTTP call to get the data and let the user know that the data is fresh, and show in the interface the next data refresh time, with a count down or a visual graphic
- if the data don't change much, would go with your solution of add Json data as a variable to be used in the page to build the table after the page loads.

hope it helps.